# How do I "conditionally" count missing values per variable in PROC SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm measuring expenses in different categories. I have two types of variables. A categorical variables which states if the respondent have had expenses in the category (such as  "Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg") and I have numerical variables (such as UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers), which provides information on the amount spent by each respondent in that category.

I want to create a table which tells me if there are missing values in my numerical variables for categories where expenses have been reported (so missing values of "UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers" where the variable "Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg" equals 1, in an example with only one variable).

This works in a simple SQL query, so something like:

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT nmiss(UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers)
FROM IBIS3_5
WHERE Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg=1;
quit;
```

But I don't want to navigate between 20 different datasets to find my missing values, I want them all in the same table. I figure this should be possible if i write a subquery in the SELECT clause for each variable, so something like:

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT (SELECT nmiss(UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers)
FROM IBIS3_5
WHERE Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg=1) as nmiss_variable_1
FROM IBIS3_5;
quit;
```

This last query does not seem to work, however. It does not return a single value, but one value for each row in the dataset.

How do I make this work?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? As any potential answers can vary

Comment: I have no idea. I'm using the PROC SQL module in SAS. I'm only working with local files so I'm not actually accessing any actual databases or anything.

Comment: Okay I can probably use the DISTINCT keyword to remove all the duplicates. It's not pretty, but seems to work.

Comment: Are you trying to test each observation as to whether or not it is missing (which is what you code is doing) Or do you want the total (aka SUM() ) of the number of missing values for the whole dataset?  Or do you just want to test if there are ANY missing values without necessarily getting the count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to generate a single value.

Either the total number of mis-matches.

```
select sum(missing(UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers) and Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg=1) as nmiss
  from ibis3_5
;
```

Or perhaps just a binary 1/0 flag of whether or not there are any mismatches.

```
select max(missing(UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers) and Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg=1) as any_miss
  from ibis3_5
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a good usage of proc freq instead. Especially if you have multiple values.

Not all of this is necessary but this is a missing report. Depends exactly how you're defining missing of course.

```
*create sample data to work with;

data class;
    set sashelp.class;

    if age=14 then
        call missing(height, weight, sex);

    if name='Alfred' then
        call missing(sex, age, height);
    label age="Fancy Age Label";
run;

*set input data set name;
%let INPUT_DSN = class;
%let OUTPUT_DSN = want;
*create format for missing;

proc format;
    value $ missfmt ' '="Missing" other="Not Missing";
    value nmissfmt .="Missing" other="Not Missing";
run;

*Proc freq to count missing/non missing;
ods select none;
*turns off the output so the results do not get too messy;
ods table onewayfreqs=temp;

proc freq data=&INPUT_DSN.;
    table _all_ / missing;
    format _numeric_ nmissfmt. _character_ $missfmt.;
run;

ods select all;
*Format output;

data long;
    length variable $32. variable_value $50.;
    set temp;
    Variable=scan(table, 2);
    Variable_Value=strip(trim(vvaluex(variable)));
    presentation=catt(frequency, " (", trim(put(percent/100, percent7.1)), ")");
    keep variable variable_value frequency percent cum: presentation;
    label variable='Variable' variable_value='Variable Value';
run;

proc sort data=long;
    by variable;
run;

*make it a wide data set for presentation, with values as N (Percent);

proc transpose data=long out=wide_presentation (drop=_name_);
    by variable;
    id variable_value;
    var presentation;
run;

*transpose only N;

proc transpose data=long out=wide_N prefix=N_;
    by variable;
    id variable_value;
    var frequency;
run;

*transpose only percents;

proc transpose data=long out=wide_PCT prefix=PCT_;
    by variable;
    id variable_value;
    var percent;
run;

*final output file;

data &Output_DSN.;
    merge wide_N wide_PCT wide_presentation;
    by variable;
    drop _name_;
    label N_Missing='# Missing' N_Not_Missing='# Not Missing' 
        PCT_Missing='% Missing' N_Not_Missing='% Not Missing' Missing='Missing' 
        Not_missing='Not Missing';
run;

title "Missing Report of &INPUT_DSN.";

proc print data=&output_dsn. noobs label;
run;
```